# Chords between i and an augmented-sixth chord

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-progressions

I am wondering about chords that can go between i and different augmented-sixth chords. Are there any resources on this? I've googled and searched past questions and didn't find anything...

edit: in the context of a second-semester college harmony course

Comment: Any chord can go before or after or between any other chords.

Comment: see edit, I mean in the context of a second-semester college harmony course, as in contrapunctally

Comment: Sorry, by A6, do you literally mean a chord consisting of A, C#, E, and F#? You're mixing two sets of chord notations, so I don't quite know what you mean.

Comment: I mean an Augmented 6th chord

Answer (score 2):

When we think of the bassline, we see that we'll have scale-degree 1 in the bass of the tonic moving to scale-degree 6 in the bass of the augmented sixth. What's especially common connecting those two chords is having a lowered scale-degree 7 in the bass.

As such, if you're moving directly from tonic to the augmented sixth, I'd recommend v6 as the passing chord between them. Notice that this will be a *minor* chord on account of having the subtonic in the bass as opposed to the leading tone. (It won't be the leading tone, because then we'd have an augmented second between it and the lowered scale-degree 6 of the augmented-sixth chord.)

But if we can insert two chords in between, it's especially common to have a V42/iv after tonic which then resolves to a iv6. Then it's just a slight change from the iv6 to the augmented sixth. This is especially nice because of the chromatic motion in an upper voice from scale-degree 3 of the tonic chord up to the raised scale-degree 4 of the augmented sixth.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the classical music I've listened to, you don't even need to insert any chords in between i and an augmented 6th chord.

Chords I have heard inserted between i and an augmented 6th chord and put immediately before the augmented 6th chord include V (J. C. Heed's "In Storm and Sunshine"), ♭II a.k.a. the Neapolitan (Franz Schubert's Moments Musicaux No. 5 in F Minor), and (♭)VI (Moments Musicaux No. 5 again).

I'd imagine that vii°6/5 of V would be a good chord to put between i and an augmented 6th chord, though, as it's one note away from a German Augmented 6th, and the root of vii°6/5 of V moves nicely down one semitone to the root of the German Augmented 6th (e.g., in F minor, D-F-A♭-B to D♭-F-A♭-B).

Often, there is more than one chord between i and an augmented 6th chord.